# How to give a certain high to tab in tab bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar

I am trying to achieve this result for the tab bar in a flutter that shows the selected and unselected tabs, my problem is here that I cannot give a certain height to tabs can you help me please.

[THIS IS MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYyjB.jpg)

I want to achieve this

[image: I want to achieve this]`

Comment: Can you include code instead of code-image, check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check my example

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: [
              TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                  Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                  Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                  height: 500,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                    ],
                  ))
            ]))));
}
```

here don't use Tab widget inside the `TabBar`  because it has some default  property ,instead of using Tab inside the tab bar ,use Container

like this way

```
           TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                  Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                  Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                ],
              ),
```

using this way , you can achieve  it , if you want change color or etc ... according to selection use index of `TabController` and `index`

and also all property of `TabBar` will work this way too

out put will be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have  to set the height of the tab based on your requirement with MediaQuery

Answer (score 0):

`Tab` comes with `height` property, you can use it to provide height for tab.

```dart
Tab( height: 100,...)
```

> If [`height`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tab/height.html) is null, the height will be calculated based on the content of the Tab. When icon is not null along with child or text, the default height is 72.0 pixels. Without an icon, the height is 46.0 pixels.